# Cordova Phone Push Plugin Multiple Push Notifications Creating, Always open last send push notification when tapped

Tags: angularjs, cordova

Cordova Phone Push Plugin Multiple Push Notifications Creating but not opening when tapped on the created notification

Always open last send push notification

Comment: so... where is the question?